# Hide Tab when it is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I've searched this page for an answer but I didn't find one.

I have following bootstrap-tabs:

```
<div class="dt-container">
    <ul id="description-tabs" class="nav nav-tabs tabs-responsive" role="tablist">
       <li class="active">
           <a id="tab-description" href="#tab1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Description</a>
       </li>
       <li>
           <a id="tab-technicaldata" href="#tab2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Details</a>
       </li>
    </ul>

    <div class="panel-container">
       <div id="tab1">Lorem ipsum</div>
       <div id="tab2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How do i hide the the *tab2* which contains no content at all.

I tried it with this script. It actually was hiding the tab with no content but I was not able to click on any of the tabs:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        var $tabs = $( "#dt-container" );
        $tabs.tabs();
        var offst = 0;
        $('#dt-container > div > div').each(function(index, elem) {
            if ($(elem).html().trim() === '') {
                $tabs.tabs( "remove" , index - offst);
                offst++;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: First you have `<div class="dt-container">`, but later you select `$( "#dt-container" )`. `dt-container` is a class, you should select it as `$( ".dt-container" )`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go with a solution http://jsfiddle.net/xFW8t/2751/

```js
$(function () {
    $('.panel-container').children().each(function(){
      if($(this).contents().length === 0)
       $('a[href="#' + $(this).attr('id') + '"]').hide();
    });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="dt-container">
    <ul id="description-tabs" class="nav nav-tabs tabs-responsive" role="tablist">
       <li class="active">
           <a id="tab-description" href="#tab1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Description</a>
       </li>
       <li>
           <a id="tab-technicaldata" href="#tab2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Details</a>
       </li>
    </ul>

    <div class="panel-container">
       <div id="tab1">Lorem ipsum</div>
       <div id="tab2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you! you saved my day!

Comment: Welcome buddy :)

Comment: but how to ignore if there are commented lines ?

Answer (score 6):

You can use the CSS `:empty` pseudo class:

```css
.panel-container > div[id^=tab] {
   padding: 10px;
   display: inline-block;
   border: 2px dashed orange;
}

.panel-container > div[id^=tab]:empty {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="dt-container">

  <div class="panel-container">
    <div id="tab1">Lorem ipsum</div>
    <div id="tab2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that the tab must be *completely* empty (no space characters).

---

If you need the related content to be hidden or removed, you can use JS for that.

```
const tabs = document.querySelectorAll(".panel-container > div[id^=tab]:empty");
for (const tab of tabs) {
  document.querySelector(`a[href="${tab.id}"]`).parentNode.remove();
}
```

Comment: I didn't know you could do this. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: But the problem is that the tab is still showing up. This CSS Code only hides the content area

Comment: @HeatLife: Not sure what you mean. I added a demo to the answer to show that it works.

Comment: Do you mean the content related to that tab?

Comment: yes exactly :-) Its more importwnt for me to hide the tab than its related content. Because the content only appers when the tab is clicked

Comment: Then you should be all set. This will hide the empty tab, as long as it's actually empty.

Answer (score 0):

You could check the length of the elements inside. If the length is zero, hide it.

```
if ($('#tab2').children().length === 0){
  $('#tab2').hide();
}
```